# colorbox callback confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, colorbox

I call the colorbox twice. First call is on click. When colorbox is open, you can print its content on click:

```
$("a.nivoImageLink").colorbox({
    opacity:.8,
    onComplete:function() {
        cboxPrint(false);
    }
});
```

And second: colorbox opens on the thumbnails print-icon click, the print window open, after print procedure the colorbox closes again:

```
$("a.print").click(function() {
    $("a.nivoImageLink:not(:hidden)").colorbox({
        open:true,
        onComplete:function() {
            cboxPrint(true);
        }
    });
});
```

This works so far. But when I open the colorbox on the print-icon (second call), the colorbox opens just in that case, regardless of which call I do. This is the callback function:

```
function cboxPrint(autoprint) {
    if (autoprint) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.print(); 
            $.colorbox.close();
        },800);
    } else {
        $("a.cboxPrint").click(function() { 
            window.print(); 
        });
    }
};
```

can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understood your question, it is still too early in the morning ^^. Have you considered how colorbox works? Once colorbox has been opened, it creates some markup and then just hides that from view, and unhides it when you want to show it again. If I remember correctly. You may need to clear the colorbox code if you are getting weird results from multiple colorboxes on the page.

You could use:

```
$.colorbox.remove()
```

This would truly clear all traces of colorbox code from your document. There are more elegant ways of dealing with this problem like using the onClosed callback function.

Although, as I said before, I didn't quite understand your problem so this may be of little interest to you. Good luck all the same :)

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry, maybe my question is not clear enough. Short and hopefully clear: I use one callback function for two different colorbox calls, just give a "autoprint" true or false with the function to differ the effect. When I click the second call, we say "autoprint == true", the other will be true too, regardless to it has to be "autoprint == false". That's all.

I know the remove() thing, but then I have to reinitialize the colorbox for other assets. I think I just have to do two different functions, its not so beautiful but it will work.

Comment: Ah, yes, well javascript often ends up being a less beautiful than we hope it could be. I see I completely missed your problem ^^ I was having a problem with true and false in js earlier this morning and my ifs and else just didn't seem to work. I used if(data === true) { ...} else { ... } . Using triple equality ('===') checks that values are the same value and the same type. I'm no guru with javascript I'm afraid, I'm content when things work ^^ But good to see you found your solution, have a good one